# ARKit sceneView.projectPoint return incorrect value

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

The essence of the problem is that if you rotate the device along the Y axis, for example, to the right, then at some point the object that is to the left of the device, the X value from negative becomes positive, although the object is still to the left of the device. The same thing works with another turn in the other direction. And also this behavior is present if you tilt the device vertically - first the Y coordinate is as positive as possible, if the object is on top of the phone, then sharply as negative as possible.

I need to implement a directional arrow to the object if it is not in the field of view. Because of this bug, my arrow starts pointing in the wrong direction. Can you tell me how to solve it?

I have implemented special logic to check this "inversion", which converts incorrect values into correct ones, but it does not always work and this is definitely not the best solution[image]

Comment: You need to provide example code (see [mre]) showing what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've already done that. The screenshot shows the output of SceneView.projectPoint(targetNode.position) with a smooth rotation. Pay attention to X, which from the maximum negative abruptly becomes the largest positive

Comment: Yes, I see your output... looks very similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397085/arkit-2d-projection-result-for-a-point-in-3d-space-changes-abruptly-at-certain -- so, if you put together a [mre] and post it somewhere such as GitHub, we can run that code, see what's happening, and maybe (hopefully) find a solution.